# How to make Mathematica express an equation in terms of previously defined functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, variable

I was given a problem for my physics class, and perhaps I have taken it too far, but I wish to finish what I started. I have a function (i warn you that this does not look pretty)

```
y[t]:= E^(1/2*(Sqrt[-4*g + b^2/m^2] - b/m)*t) (-((h*m)/2) + (-b*h + v)/
    Sqrt[-4*g + b^2/m^2]) + 
 1/2*E^(1/2 (-Sqrt[-4*g + b^2/m^2] - b/m) t)
   h*(1 - (b*h - 2*m*v)/Sqrt[b^2*h^2*m^2 - 4 g*h^2*m^2])
```

*
as a point of reference, the only variable in the equation is t, all others (b, m, h, v, and g) are constants
*

Now this equation describes the motion of a falling "particle" in a uniform gravitational field. So far so good. Now you can find the "terminal velocity" of this "particle" by the following performing the following, ideally that is.

*
the actual equation in my physics text book looks like the following

```
(d/dt)*m*y'[t]=0
*

Solve[D[m*D[y[t],t],t]==0,D[y[t],t]]
```

Mathematica didn't very much like that. So what I did that I thought would help was to name

```
y1[t]:= D[y[t],t]
```

Where

```
y1[t] = 1/2 E^(1/2 (Sqrt[-4 g + b^2/m^2] - b/m) t) (Sqrt[-4 g + b^2/m^2] - b/m)*(-((h*m)/2) + (-b*h + v)/Sqrt[-4*g + b^2/m^2]) + 
 1/4 E^(1/2 (-Sqrt[-4 g + b^2/m^2] - b/m)*t)
  *h*(-Sqrt[-4 g + b^2/m^2] - b/m) (1 - (b*h - 2*m*v)/Sqrt[
    b^2*h^2*m^2 - 4*g*h^2*m^2])
```

Where y1[t] would be the equivalent of y'[t] in the previously stated formula. So now what I want to be able to do is the derivative of y1[t] in terms of y1[t] instead of the terms from the entire function.

To repeat, what I get for D[m*y1[t],t] or D[m*D[y[t],t],t], which I name y2[t] is

```
y2[t] := m*(1/4*E^(
    1/2*(Sqrt[-4*g + b^2/m^2] - b/m)*t)*(Sqrt[-4*g + b^2/m^2] - b/
      m)^2 (-((h*m)/2) + (-b*h + v)/Sqrt[-4*g + b^2/m^2]) + 
   1/8*E^(1/2*(-Sqrt[-4*g + b^2/m^2] - b/m)*t)
     h*(-Sqrt[-4*g + b^2/m^2] - b/m)^2 (1 - (b*h - 2*m*v)/Sqrt[
      b^2*h^2*m^2 - 4*g*h^2*m^2]))
```

Effectively what I want is to see y2[t] expressed in terms of y1[t]. Not with all the b's, m's, h's, v's, and g's. I get that there will be a few of those constants with a few binary operations or whatever, but all I really need is to see y1[t] terms expressed in the function y2[t].

Comment: Consider differentiating the right side of your first expression, equate it to zero, and `Solve` it for `t`.  With this result, you can obtain `y` and related quantities at that point, if you wish.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have translated the physics problem into Mathematica is the source of the problem.

```
Solve[D[m*D[y[t], t], t] == 0, D[y[t], t]]
```

If your remove D[y[t] from the above expression then `Solve` will yield a solution.

```
solution = Solve[D[m*D[y[t], t], t] == 0, t]

{{t -> (I π)/Sqrt[(b^2 - 4 g m^2)/m^2] + (1/Sqrt[((
    b^2 - 4 g m^2)/(
    m^2))])(Log[1/4 b Sqrt[-4 g + b^2/m^2] + b^2/(4 m) - (g m)/2] - 
      Log[(b^2 h)/4 - (b^3 h)/(2 Sqrt[-4 g + b^2/m^2] m) + (b g h m)/
        Sqrt[-4 g + b^2/m^2] + 1/4 b h Sqrt[-4 g + b^2/m^2] m + 
        1/2 g h m^2 - (b v)/2 + (b^2 v)/(2 Sqrt[-4 g + b^2/m^2] m) - (
        g m v)/Sqrt[-4 g + b^2/m^2]])}}
```

Now you can insert this solution into the expression for D[y[t]]

```
D[y[t],t] /. solution[[1, 1]]
```

This is fairly long so I will not copy it in this answer.